# Can I use JavaScript to add an input field to a form?

Tags: javascript, forms

Problem: Because the form is controlled by another company, they only allow me to add tracking codes, but I need to add my own form input fields, so I figure using JavaScript for this may be possible:

The original form looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="http://subdomain.somewebsite.com">
<input type="hidden" name="client_id" value="160">
<input type="hidden" name="source" value="http://subdomain.somewebsite.com/survey/123">
<fieldset>
<div class="form-group input_text" id="fld-name">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input  class="form-control" type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" placeholder="Name"  required/>
</div>
<div class="form-group input_text" id="fld-email">
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input  class="form-control" type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email"  required/>
</div>
<div class="form-group input_text" id="fld-phone">
  <label for="phone">Phone</label>
  <input  class="form-control" type="text" id="phone" name="phone" value="" placeholder="Phone"  required/>
</div>
<button name="submit-now" id="submit-now" data-lb-name="Button Text" data-lb="editable-rich-text" data-lb-id="btn"> Save <b>$</b> Today! </button>
</fieldset>
```

And this is what I need to add to it (via js):

```
<input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" maxlength="10" size="10"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Click-to-Call"  onclick="window.open('http://example.com/clickto_status.php?click_id=123&phone_to_call=' + getElementById('phone').value + '&key=123123123123123abc', 'Clickto' , 'width=200,height=200,toolbar=no,location=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, copyhistory=no,resizable=no')">
```

I might end up removing the popup code, but not sure yet.

I am very NOOB so pleae type slowly please. Thank you in advance

Comment: Search in google. You should get the element node of the fieldset. Then use document.createElement then addAttribute for each attribute, and then appendCHild. Good luck, doing it yourself will help you more than a copy paste answer my frien

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it like this:

```
var url = "http://example.com/clickto_status.php?click_id=123&phone_to_call=";

$('form').append('<input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" maxlength="10" size="10"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Click-to-Call"  onclick="window.open(url + getElementById('phone').value + '&key=123123123123123abc', 'Clickto' , 'width=200,height=200,toolbar=no,location=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, copyhistory=no,resizable=no')">');
```

Or if you dont wanna use jquery do this --

**Option 2:**

give your form an id like this

and then do this

```
<form id='myform' ....// your html

document.getElementById('myform').append('<input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" maxlength="10" size="10"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Click-to-Call"  onclick="window.open(url + getElementById('phone').value + '&key=123123123123123abc', 'Clickto' , 'width=200,height=200,toolbar=no,location=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, copyhistory=no,resizable=no')">');
```